# redirect page using ajax & jquery (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to redirect from page a to page profile and in between there is a post session on them. in this case let's say the data is variable `$name` in string. so far my code is like this on page a

```
            jQuery("#result").on("click",function(e){ 
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
            var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
            $('#searchid').val(decoded); 
            //the ajax script    
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'b.php',
            data: 'result='+$name,
            success: function() {
               window.location.href = "profile.php";  // replace
            }
            });      
            });
```

and on `page b` the code is:

```
<?php echo $_POST['result']?>
```

the outcome should be the value from `result` in which determined on `page a`.
but so there is an error message saying `unidentified index`. so where am i doing wrong?

Comment: on which line it shows `undefined index` ?

Comment: How does the html look?

Comment: I tried this and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Albin the error occured when i call the data on page profile. it is actually an autocomplete search and when i click on the name, it directs me into the profile page. the above code is the click function.

Comment: @Arun it shows on the profile page. it seems does not recognize the $_POST['result'] data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be, that your data parameter is wrong?
I have my ajax calls as folowing:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "b.php",
  data: {
    result: $name
  },
  success: function() {
    window.location.href = "profile.php";  // replace
  }
});
```

Comment: how do you call the data on profile page? because it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a new request after the redirect. In order to access the result you need to sotre it in som kind of session or pass it again.

You can pass it like this, then it will be in $_GET

```
success: function(data) {
  window.location.href = "profile.php?result="+data;  // replace
}
```